# How to connect MYSQL with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am stuck after writing all the code, the Website just doesn't connect with mysql at all!

Comment: Your sentence is invalid, how is HTML supposed to connect with MySQL? and what have you tried so far to achieve this

Comment: This is an extremely broad, confusing question with no code provided at all. How do you expect anyone to help you?

Comment: @jeremy Can we see what you are trying to achieve? - The code

Comment: Did you write any code to make a connection? If so, why haven't you shown it? What goes wrong, what error do you get? If you haven't written anything, why not? There are billions of examples available online, starting not least with the official PHP documentation.

Answer (score 2):

I think this code will help

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,$dbname);

?>
```

write this code in html file and save it as .php
I hope it works

Comment: Where is your DB Name?

Answer (score -1):

Create a database in phpmyadmin and then write down below code in a file and save it with `.php` extension

```
<?php
    $db_username = "db_username";  // Your database login username 
    $db_password = "db_password";  // Your database login password
    $db_name = "db_name";      // The name of the database you wish to use
    $db_host = "db_host";   // The address of the database. Often this is localhost, but may be for example db.yoursite.com
    $conn = new mysqli($db_host, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name);
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }
?>
```

set those 4 variable as per your db details. `mysqli_connect_error()` will give you error if the connection will not establish

Comment: I have edit my answer. Now any reason why it is downvoted?

Comment: "$db_username AND $db_password can be root" . Really bad idea. Don't encourage this. No application should ever connect as root, it's a hacking attempt waiting to happen. If you remove that suggestion, your answer is better than the other one because it shows how to handle an error.